# What Mocha API call will stub a method which takes no arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocha.js

I seem to only find SO posts asking how to assert that a method has no return value but what I want is to require that a method call in my tests never see any arguments passed to the method.

I expected to find some documentation in http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/ParameterMatchers.html, but no luck ... should I be looking elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for the `with` method](https://github.com/freerange/mocha/blob/036b2d37b4305e355fbcb373ed11132525e94cf7/lib/mocha/expectation.rb) doesn't appear to say this, but I discovered that calling `with()` with no parameters will force Mocha to check that the method call happens with no arguments.

Example:

```
MyClass.any_instance.stubs(:its_method).with.return true
```